# Embed a GTK Widget into a Qt Window

Tags: gtk, qt5, chromium-embedded, qx11embedcontainer

I need to develop an application for *Windows*, *Linux* and *Mac*. To not have to write all the window cruft myself I chose to use *Qt5* (over *wxWidgets*, because the latter ship no precompiled binaries). I have a *GTK* Widget (of [Cef](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/)) which I now need to embed, but sadly have no idea how.

There seems to have been `QX11EmbedContainer` in previous versions of *Qt*, but it is not present anymore and also I am not sure this works, when there is a switch to *Weyland*.

Comment: I have the same problem as you, can you please share with me what didi you do?

Comment: I did use Qt Webkit. It works fairly well but since there is no version beyond 4.8 for Ubuntu LTS I am stuck with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the QT WebKit if you need just a embed browser

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwebkit/qtwebkit-index.html

Comment: QtWebkit is ancient and in no way compares to Cef. So no, not an option.

Comment: Had to reevaluate the necessities and go with Qt Webkit.

Answer (score 1):

```
    QMainWindow* main_window = new QMainWindow;
    QX11EmbedContainer* container = new QX11EmbedContainer;
    main_window->setCentralWidget(container);

    //gtk code
    GtkWidget* window;
    GtkWidget* button;
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    button = gtk_button_new ();
    gtk_widget_show (button);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), button);
    gtk_widget_show(window);
    XID id = GDK_WINDOW_XWINDOW (GTK_WIDGET(window)->window);

    container->embedClient(id);
```

you can use QX11EmbedContainer class on Qt4.

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)

Answer (score 1):

It's been 7 years, but I've dealt with this before. Here's what I found[1](https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=13938&start=20):

> I found a way to properly embed CEF inside a Qt window: embedding it inside an empty QWindow instead of a QWidget. There are some caveats, though:
>
> 1. To add the CEF window into a QWidget layout, you will need to use QWidget::createWindowContainer()
> 2. An empty QWindow doesn't render anything -- not even a background. So, you might need to use a QBackingStore to make it render something when CEF isn't embedded -- see the Raster Window example for some reference.
> 3. You might need to use the winId from before you add the QWindow into your widget's layout.

I highly recommend anyone still trying this to take a look at the entire thread[1](https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=13938&start=20). QtWebkit is not longer an acceptable solution, while CEF centainly is.